# RecyclerView OnClick Position

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the position of a clicked item for my `RecyclerView`. However, it is being a little odd and is only letting me log the position when clicked and not letting me make a `Toast` of the position. See here:

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<Country> countries;
private int rowLayout;
private Context mContext;



public MainAdapter(List<Country> countries, int rowLayout, Context context) {
    this.countries = countries;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    this.mContext = context;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView countryName;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryName);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("RecyclerView", "onClick：" + getPosition());
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }


}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Country country = countries.get(position);
    viewHolder.countryName.setText(country.name);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return countries == null ? 0 : countries.size();
}
}
```

If I uncomment the `Toast` of the position when an item is clicked, the app will crash, but the log seems to work fine. How would I be able to fix it so I can `Toast` the position of an item when clicked?

Comment: For us to be able to help you, we need to see what the error message that you're getting is. Please edit your question and add it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd need to see the error message that you're getting to be sure, but it's probably because you're passing the wrong arguments into the `Toast`.

Your `Toast` looks like this:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`getPosition` returns an `int`, and the `makeText()` method is expecting a `String` for the second parameter.

Change your `Toast` to this:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Position: " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Update:**

`getPosition` is deprecated now, You can use `getLayoutPosition`

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: FYI, adding an integer to the 2nd parameter of Toast.makeText is dangerous. It will deal the integer as resource ID for some strings and your app could failed to build. You should be aware of that.