# Linear Layout onclick listener not working with recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with Recycleview in linearLayout. In the below code When I click on chat section(Linear Layout) Toast is not getting visible when I set LayoutManager to RecycleView. Please help me the toast will be visible when I click on linear layout.

Activity code:

```
public class PracticeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice);
        setLayoutViews();
    }

    private void setLayoutViews(){

        // setting up messages list view
        RecyclerView mMessagesView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages);

        // if i uncomment below line Toast will not be visible.
        //mMessagesView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        (findViewById(R.id.chat_section)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(PracticeActivity.this, " Chat section was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

activity_practice.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chat_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:background="@color/chat_back_ground">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/messages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
        </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
           android:layout_below="@id/chat_section"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Just text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: itemView.setOnClickListener(this); use in your adapter viewHolder class

Comment: you need ViewHolder check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790971/no-toast-shown-when-item-clicked-recyclerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial. The process followed is to create a separate itemtouchlistener class from which the selection is identified

http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/